# Using 2 dropdowns in React. Cannot read property 'map' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux

I'm having an issue with 2 dropdowns. I'm getting the following error: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined`.

Both dropdowns should work at the same time depending if the user wants to select a value from one of them or wants to select values from both dropdowns.

This is how I have implemented my 2 Dropdowns and how they should work. If I click the button I will get the error: [image]

dropdown.js

```
import * as actionTypes from '../actions';

const initialState = {
    selection: 'Ambos',
    dropdownValues: ['Chatbot', 'Agente'],

    selectionME: 'Todos',
    dropdownValuesME: ['Messenger', 'Web', 'WhatsApp']

};
//
const reducer = ( state = initialState, action ) => {
    if (typeof state === 'undefined') {
        return initialState
    }

    switch ( action.type ) {
        case actionTypes.UPDATE_SELECTION:
        {
            return {
                
                ...state,
                selection: action.dataSelected,
                dropdownValues: action.dropdownValues,

                selectionME: action.dataSelectedME,
                dropdownValuesME: action.dropdownValuesME
            }
        }
        default: {
         //statements;
         
         break;
        }
    }
    return state;
};


export default reducer;
```

DropdownSelect.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { ButtonDropdown, DropdownToggle, DropdownMenu, DropdownItem } from 'reactstrap';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import * as actionTypes from '../../store/actions'

class DropdownSelect extends Component {

  constructor(props)
{
  super(props);
  console.log(props)
  this.state = {
    dropdownOpen: false,
    solved: this.props.selectData,
    dropdownValues: this.props.dropdownValues,

    dropdownOpenME: false,
    solvedME: this.props.selectDataME,
    dropdownValuesME: this.props.dropdownValuesME,
  }
}

componentDidMount() {
  if(this.props.onRef)
  this.props.onRef(this);

}

toggleDropdown = () => {
  this.setState({
    dropdownOpen: !this.state.dropdownOpen,
  });
}

toggleDropdown2 = () => {
  this.setState({
    dropdownOpenME: !this.state.dropdownOpenME,
  });
}

changeDropdownValue = async (event) => {
    const currentSolved = this.state.solved
    let newdropdownValues = this.state.dropdownValues.concat(currentSolved)
    newdropdownValues = newdropdownValues.filter(item => item !== event.target.innerText)

    await this.setState({
        dropdownOpen: !this.state.dropdownOpen,
        solved: event.target.innerText,
        dropdownValues: newdropdownValues,

    }, () => {
       this.props.onUpdate(this.state.solved, this.state.dropdownValues);
    });
}
changeDropdownValueME = async (event) => {
  const currentSolvedME = this.state.solvedME
  let newdropdownValuesME = this.state.dropdownValuesME.concat(currentSolvedME)
  newdropdownValuesME = newdropdownValuesME.filter(item2 => item2 !== event.target.innerText)

  await this.setState({
      dropdownOpenME: !this.state.dropdownOpenME,
      solvedME: event.target.innerText,
      dropdownValuesME: newdropdownValuesME

  }, () => {
     this.props.onUpdate(this.state.solvedME, this.state.dropdownValuesME);
  });
}

  render() {
    return (
    <>                              
      <ButtonDropdown isOpen={this.state.dropdownOpen} toggle={this.toggleDropdown}>
        <DropdownToggle caret>
        {this.state.solved}
        </DropdownToggle>
        <DropdownMenu>
          {this.state.dropdownValues.map(e => {return <DropdownItem key={e} onClick={this.changeDropdownValue}>{e}</DropdownItem>})}
        </DropdownMenu>
      </ButtonDropdown>
      
      <p className="text-uppercase text-left font-weight-bold -label">Tipo de atención</p>
      <ButtonDropdown isOpen={this.state.dropdownOpenME} toggle={this.toggleDropdown2}>
        <DropdownToggle caret>
        {this.state.solvedME}
        </DropdownToggle>
        <DropdownMenu>
          {this.state.dropdownValuesME.map(e => {return <DropdownItem key={e} onClick={this.changeDropdownValueME}>{e}</DropdownItem>})}
        </DropdownMenu>
      </ButtonDropdown>

      </>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  //selectData: state.dropDownReducer.selection || [],
  //dropdownValues: state.dropDownReducer.dropdownValues || ['Ambos', 'Chatbot', 'Agente'],
  selectData: state.dropDownReducer.selection,
  dropdownValues: state.dropDownReducer.dropdownValues,

  selectDataME: state.dropDownReducer.selectionME,
  dropdownValuesME: state.dropDownReducer.dropdownValuesME
});

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
    return {
        onUpdate: (selected, dropdownValues) => dispatch({type: actionTypes.UPDATE_SELECTION, dataSelected: selected, dropdownValues:dropdownValues})
          }
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(DropdownSelect);
```

Answer (score 2):

hey Jorge try to add conditions before mapping the data

```
        <DropdownMenu>
          {this.state.dropdownValues && this.state.dropdownValues.map(e => {return <DropdownItem key={e} onClick={this.changeDropdownValue}>{e}</DropdownItem>})}
        </DropdownMenu>
```

the same here

```
{this.state.dropdownValuesME && this.state.dropdownValuesME.map(e => {return <DropdownItem key={e} onClick={this.changeDropdownValueME}>{e}</DropdownItem>})}
```

and I believe you should not assign the state directly from the props, you should create the state as an empty array
then in the component did mount you should set the state with the new values

```
  this.state = {
    dropdownOpen: false,
    solved: this.props.selectData,
    dropdownValues: [],

    dropdownOpenME: false,
    solvedME: this.props.selectDataME,
    dropdownValuesME: [],
  }
}

componentDidMount() {
  if(this.props.onRef)
  this.props.onRef(this);
  this.setState(oldState => {...oldState, dropdownValues: this.props.dropdownValues ,dropdownValuesME: this.props.dropdownValuesME})
}
```

Comment: Thank you, Fadi Omar. But still not working. Whats happening is that both data from dropdowns are getting combined.

Comment: first, return the state in default switch in your reducer
and can you add console in the componentDidMount for 
```console.log({drop1: this.props.dropdownValues, drop2: this.props.dropdownValuesME})
```
and paste the result here to figure it out

Comment: this is the result when loading the page: ```dropdownValues: (2) ["Chatbot", "Agente"]
dropdownValuesME: (3) ["Messenger", "Web", "WhatsApp"]
onUpdate: ƒ onUpdate(selected, dropdownValues)
selectData: "Ambos"
selectDataME: "Todos"
__proto__: Object```

Comment: but if i chose between the dropdowns: this happens ```dropdownValues: (3) ["Web", "WhatsApp", "Todos"]
dropdownValuesME: undefined
onUpdate: ƒ onUpdate(selected, dropdownValues)
selectData: "Messenger"
selectDataME: undefined
__proto__: Object```